# Strange get_the_* behavior with php 5.4

Tags: plugins, shortcode, get-posts

Let me try to explain what happened to me :

I have a shortcode plugin which display child pages of the current page (a mod of http://wpist.me/wp/child-pages-shortcode/, very useful).

In the display function, it uses get_posts(), with very basic code, conform to the codex examples (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) :

```
global $post;
foreach ($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $html = $post->post_title;
    $html .= get_the_excerpt();
    $html .= get_the_content();
}
```

With PHP 5.2, it works as expected. I updated to PHP 5.4, and get_the_content() is returning the parent content, instead of the current child. Previous lines are still returning the correct data, but it seems that the first call to a get_the_* function changes the content of the global $post.

It works fine if I use $post->* instead of get_the_*(), but get_the_*() has useful automatic treatment.

I found a way to make it work, so I post it here, so maybe someone can explain me why it's behave like this.

1. I changed the name of the loop var to avoid messing the global $post (I don't understand why codex example use $post in their loop, by the way…)
2. I added a setup_postdata call after each get_the_*() calls to reinit the global to the correct post :

working code :

```
global $post;
foreach ($pages as $mypost) {
    setup_postdata($mypost);
    $html = $mypost->post_title;
    $html .= get_the_excerpt();
    setup_postdata($mypost);
    $html .= get_the_content();
}
```

thanks

Edit : the full code of my function (this is working correctly) in case the simplified version confuses you :

```
private function display($param, $block_template)
{      
global $post;

$html = '';
// defining the content of $template
// cut
// end defining $template

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $param['id'],
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'nopaging' => true,
);
$args = apply_filters('child-pages-shortcode-query', $args, $param);

$pages = get_posts($args);
foreach ($pages as $post2) {
    setup_postdata($post2);
    $post = apply_filters('child_pages_shortcode_post', $post2);
    $url = get_permalink($post2->ID);
    $img = get_the_post_thumbnail($post2->ID, $param['size']);
    $img = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $img);
    $tpl = $template;
    $tpl = str_replace('%width%', esc_attr($param['width']), $tpl);
    $tpl = str_replace('%post_id%', intval($post2->ID), $tpl);
    $tpl = str_replace('%post_title%', $post2->post_title, $tpl);
    $tpl = str_replace('%post_subtitle%', get_post_meta($post2->ID, "Sous titre", true), $tpl);
    $tpl = str_replace('%post_url%', esc_url($url), $tpl);
    $tpl = str_replace('%post_thumb%', $img, $tpl);
    if (isset($param['disabled_excerpt_filters']) && $param['disabled_excerpt_filters']) {
        $tpl = str_replace('%post_excerpt%', $post2->post_excerpt, $tpl);
    } else {
        $tpl = str_replace('%post_excerpt%', get_the_excerpt(), $tpl);
        setup_postdata($post2);
    }
    if (isset($param['disabled_excerpt_filters']) && $param['disabled_excerpt_filters']) {
        $tpl = str_replace('%post_content%', $post2->post_content, $tpl);
    } else {
        $tpl = str_replace('%post_content%', get_the_content(), $tpl);
    }
    $html .= $tpl;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

if (!$block_template) {
    $html .= '<hr style="border:0px; clear:both;"></div>';
}

return apply_filters("child-pages-shortcode-output", $html);
}
```

Comment: you're redefining `$html` with every operation. Do you mean to be concatenating? `$html .= 'something else';`

Comment: No, it's a very simplified version of my code. You can ignore this.

Comment: Seems this has a lot to do with this plugin: [WordPress › Child Pages Shortcode « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/child-pages-shortcode/) -- tried running your code without the shortcode/plugin reference?

Answer (score 0):

With all of the `get_the_*` flavor of functions, you have the option of passing an ID. Why not do:

`$html .= get_the_excerpt($post->ID);`

Otherwise it's implying the originating post ID.

Comment: Are you sure ? it's not documented… http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: Ok - with "many" of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

You actually *need* to name var `$post` for everything to work smoothly. `setup_postdata()` is not actually setting `$post`'s data, is just uses it for *rest* of global stuff.

Either you are not showing enough code to see what might be going wrong or `get_` function has something hooked inside of it that messes up global.

Comment: Along these lines, I think it odd that `$post` is globalized prior to this `foreach`

Comment: Me too. But it's in the third example of the codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: I can't make it work by using $post in the loop. But it works fine with $mypost.

Comment: Globalized `$post` _is_ correct for custom loop. If this is going wrong it's due to something not part of code displayed.

Comment: I don't have the time to made a simple test case, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't work in PHP 5.4 when using $post in the loop. It looks like a change in the context behavior of PHP...

Comment: @Matthieu recreating your initial loop in PHP works just fine for me. One has to be doing really crazy things for PHP version change to affect them.

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use ? It was working fine for me with 5.2, and it stopped working as soon as I updated to 5.4

Comment: My local stack has PHP 5.4.15

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12504/discussion-between-matthieu-and-rarst)